# What is the output to make following code pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, github, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I'm currently going through the last chapter of the Ruby on Rails guides and i can't seem to figure out the problem i have at the moment. This is the output in my localhost/home page after inputting this particular code: `@user.followed_users.count`

```
2: <div class="stats">
3:   <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
4:     <strong id="following" class="stat">
5:       <%= @user.followed_users.count %>
6:     </strong>
7:     following
8:   </a>
```

and this is the error i receive.

`app/views/shared/_stats.html.erb:5:in`

`app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:8:in`

but the thing is, when i remove the code `@user.followed_users.count` it works perfectly but i wont be able to see my following count (just like in twitter) which is not part of the guides.. and part of the twitter-like application.

Here is the whole gist of the two files and i hope someone can help out and find the solution to this problem..

https://gist.github.com/2866551

any help would be very much appreciated. -Marc

Comment: above code show you the link of following user,count of followed user of particular user like  in twitter application something similar to friends. I think it is better for me if you also put the error message so I can help you in this.

Comment: @urjitrajgor ok i added the error message in my gist. please have a look

Comment: your error show there is problem in your association of user and relation ship please show me your code of user model and other related model.

Comment: @urjitrajgor ok i added both models `relationship.rb` and `user.rb` those are the only two i believe are related to this topic. `micropost.rb` i didnt add to the gist since the model has no role here..

Comment: your gist has the answer....


Could not find the source association(s) :followed_id in model Relationship. Try 'has_many :followed_users, :through => :relationships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :follower or :followed?

Comment: @drhenner actually i already have the code in my `models/user.rb` file line 7 if you look clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship in User model should be like this `has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed` not this `has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: "followed_id"` you make this change it will work fine.